# How to fetch emails using gmail oauth without username and password

Tags: php, gmail

I used xoauth to fetch mails without username and password, but it asks for granting permission to access every time

Is there any way to integrate it with google auth login

or can I add this option to apiClient page, so that it would not ask for permission every login time

```
    $options = array(
        'requestScheme' => Zend_Oauth::REQUEST_SCHEME_HEADER,
        'version' => '1.0',
        'consumerKey' => $THREE_LEGGED_CONSUMER_KEY,
        'callbackUrl' => getCurrentUrl(),
        'requestTokenUrl' => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken',
        'userAuthorizationUrl' => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken',
        'accessTokenUrl' => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken'
    );
```

This option is used in

```
$consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer($options);
```

Every time I login and this screen comes:

[image: I would like this approval screen to be disabled]

I would like this approval screen to be disabled

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done. Google will not allow you to access the user's details if the user doesn't agree (hence the confirmation screen). The user can opt to remember this choice and not to display it again, but that's out of your hands.

Comment: how to remember the choice so that next time it will not display this screen again?

Comment: According to the image you've posted, just clicking on "Grant Access" should get rid of this screen for good (i.e. Google will permanently allow access for the feature you've been trying to access). If you need a different feature from Google, the screen will appear again.

Comment: but I used the same feature and google will prompt this screen at every login time